# Not able to make corners of bottom sheet rounded in react-native-bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I am trying to make the corners of the bottom sheet provided by the [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) rounded by passing the style prop to it. But the rounded corners are being overlapped by something which I don't know. How do I make the the corners rounded?

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
<BottomSheet
    style={{ 
        flex: 1, 
        borderWidth: 5, 
        borderColor: "red", 
        backgroundColor: "blue", 
        borderRadius: 50 
    }} 
    index={1}
    ref={bottomSheetRef}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    onChange={handleSheetChange}
>
    <View 
        style={{ 
            backgroundColor: "lightgreen", 
            marginTop: 30,
            flex: 1, 
            justifyContent: 'center', 
            alignItems: 'center' 
        }}
    >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
            <Text>
                I am back
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</BottomSheet>
```

This `BottomSheet` component is wrapped inside a `View` with `flex: 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added `overflow: "hidden"` styling to the `BottomSheet`'s `style` prop and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but found another solution because I was using a `Handler` that was outside the `BottomSheet` so adding `overflow: 'hidden'` just hid my `Handler`.

Reading the code I realized that the `style` prop that is passed to `BottomSheet` is added to the code as `containerStyle` [here](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/blob/32f836b921de2c68355a44c5f5ed94afc3844fef/src/components/bottomSheet/BottomSheet.tsx#L934), but the component in charge of defining the rounded corners is actually the `BackgroundComponent` which has the border radius in its styles.

So, in order to get a `BottomSheet` with a custom corner radius is better to add a separate `backgroundComponent` with all the modifications we want.

Like this:

```js
function customBackground({ pointerEvents, style }) {
  return (
    <View
      pointerEvents={pointerEvents}
      style={[styles.bgContainer, style]}
    />
  );
}

function renderSheet(){

 return(
    <BottomSheet
      index={1}
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      onChange={handleSheetChange}
      backgroundComponent={customBackground}
    >
      <View
        style={{
            backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
            marginTop: 30,
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
            <Text>
                I am back
            </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </BottomSheet>
  ;)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bgContainer: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
})
```